# Use Apt Inside AWS VPC Without NAT Instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, apt, amazon-s3

I have several Ubuntu machines inside VPCs. For many of them, the only network access they need whatsoever is for "`apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`" and NTP. For NTP, I can simply have an NTP server with internet access inside of the VPC. But, for apt, will I have to create an apt mirror? [VPC Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-endpoints.html) seem to provide access to S3 from inside the VPC, and, apparently, there are S3 apt mirrors for Ubuntu. What is the correct way to use these S3 mirrors, or how do others manage apt updates inside of AWS VPC instances? It seems that creating a NAT instance would be overkill. I have added a VPC Endpoint but still cannot access `us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com` for example. Using `us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com.s3.amazonaws.com`, I get an HTTP connection but apt just shows failures of either 404 Page Not Found or 403 Forbidden.

Comment: Why not just associate an EIP with your machines? Or select the "public IP" option when creating them?

Comment: It's a security vulnerability. The only thing I want them having access to are the apt updates.

Comment: @Will - why do you think that what EEAA is suggesting is a security vulnerability?  just create a security group that only allows outbound and blocks all in, it's very simple and easy to set up and secure.

Comment: Allowing outbound does reduce security. "Egress filtering helps ensure that unauthorized or malicious traffic never leaves the internal network." (from wikipedia).

Comment: Because these machines don't need access to anything on the internet whatsoever. Maybe the security risk isn't significant, but the IP is still useless. Supposedly, Ubuntu apt repositories are hosted on Amazon S3, and VPC Endpoints allow access to S3 without routes out to the internet. If you feel that an Elastic IP is an ideal solution, why not just post that as an answer, rather than downvoting. I can't find any documentation on using the S3 apt repositories, and was hoping to find some help here, but I sense hostility.

Comment: We have to do the same thing for PCI compliance stuff.  Interesting thing I found is that `us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com` is not an S3 bucket.  I think it might be a group of EC2 instances.   `us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com.s3.amazonaws.com` should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 403s are expected as directory indexing is not allowed in S3.

For the 404s you may be doing something wrong. For example, http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/Release works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is no longer possible because Ubuntu no longer hosts their mirrors on S3, so VPC Endpoints are not an option.